# collectstatic collecting static files but they're not loading on webpage

Tags: django, static-files, django-deployment

I am deploying my Django site on A2 Hosting.

I can get the page to display but no static files (images/css) are loading.

I have this in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'static')]
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mysite.urls')),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='static_pages/index.html'), name='home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I am running `python manage.py collectstatic` in the terminal. It is creating a `static` folder with a file structure including `admin` and subfolders within that admin folder. My images and css files are appearing in the newly generated `static` file (in the base folder) yet neither the css nor my images are showing on my webpage (I've been restarting my server).

My link to my css file within my html template is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

This is done on shared hosting, I have debug set to false, and it works in development.

```
/home/mysite
->etc
->mysite
-->__pycache__
-->webpage
--->static
---->webpage
----->image.jpg
----->style.css
--->templates
---->webpage
----->index.html
-->main_webpage
--->settings.py
-->public
-->static_files (generated by collectstatic)
--->admin
--->image1
--->style.css
-->template
-->tmp
->logs
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: {% load static %} use it in html template or base.html

Comment: Hello. I am doing that already, at the top of my html file. Thank you.

Comment: show  tree of static directory

Comment: Sure. I added it